# How to write code that can analyse an image to find where it is non-stencilized?

Tags: php, image, pixel, stencils

I am working on a project at a company that cuts designs using a laser cutter. The company recently developed a website that allows customers to upload any image of their choice. In order to cut the design printed on the image, the design has to be a stencil. So, I have to write a software that can analyze an image to find where it is non-stencilized. If the design turns out to be non-stencilized the system should output a message such as “Design not a stencil”. I imagine this would work by understanding where a group of white pixels are enclosed by a group of black pixels. If a white pixel is completely enclosed by black pixels, then the design is not a stencil. I am not quite sure how I can write a software that can check if a white pixel is completely enclosed by black pixels. Since all the previous code for the website is written in PHP, I would prefer to use PHP.
Thanks in advance

[This is an example of a valid and invalid stencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iugqD.png)

Comment: Yes, your answer sorted out the problem. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, I think your question comes down to whether or not your image can be *"flood-filled"* - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

So, if I just use **ImageMagick** at the command line to demonstrate, and flood-fill with magenta so you can see it:

```
convert valid.png -threshold 50% -fill magenta -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png
```

[image]

And if I do the same with the invalid stencil image:

```
convert invalid.png -threshold 50% -fill magenta -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png
```

[image]

So, the solution is to flood-fill and see if there are any white pixels left afterwards. In the actual code, I will fill with black rather than magenta because, that way, I have only to find if the brightest pixel after filling is black or not to know the answer:

So, again with **ImageMagick**. Flood-fill with black and see if brightest pixel after filling is black (0) or white (255 or 65535):

```
convert valid.png -threshold 50% -fill black -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -format "%[max]" info:
0
```

and now the invalid stencil:

```
convert invalid.png -threshold 50% -fill black -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -format "%[max]" info:
65535
```

There is one little wrinkle - if the top-left pixel is not white, or the black parts touch the edge of the picture and stop the flood-fill flowing around the edges of the picture. And there is a simple solution to both, just add a 1-pixel wide white border all around the image before you start to ensure the top-left pixel is white and that the *"paint"* can flow all the way around the edges of image:

```
convert input.png -bordercolor white -border 1 .... <as before> ...
```

**PHP Version**

PHP is not my native programming language so there may be other, better ways of doing things but this seems to work ok...

```
<?php
   # Load the input image and get its size
   $name="invalid.png";
   $image=imagecreatefrompng($name);
   $size=getimagesize($name);

   # Threshold the image to only contain pure black and pure white
   imagefilter($image,IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
   imagefilter($image,IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST,-1000);

   # Flood fill white areas with black
   $black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
   imagefilltoborder($image,0,0,$black,$black);

   $allblack=1;
   # Scan the image and see if there are any non-black pixels
   for($i=0;$i<$size[0];$i++){
      for($j=0;$j<$size[1];$j++){
         $thisColor = imagecolorat($image,$i,$j);
         if($thisColor!=0){
            $allblack=0;
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   printf("%s: %d\n",$name,$allblack);

   # Write output image
   imagepng($image,"result.png");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the first time I am hearing of flood-fill but it looks like it could really work. Since I am coding in PHP, is there a built-in function in PHP that performs flood-fill? Also, why do we specify a threshold of 50% and how can I specify this threshold when coding in PHP?

Comment: I think you need `imagefilltoborder()` if you want to use `GD` library in PHP or you can use PHP ImageMagick bindings, example here http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/floodFillPaintImage

Comment: The 50% threshold sets everything above 127 to exactly white and everything below 127 to exactly black. The point is that if there is a pixel that is almost white, i.e. rgb(253,251,254), it will become exactly white and the flood fill will colour it magenta, whereas if I left it rgb(253,251,254) it would not get flood-filled.

Comment: The PHP GD function `imagefilltoborder()` is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilltoborder.php In general, `GD` is more likely to be installed on any given server, so I would tend to use that unless I absolutely needed ImageMagick which is more powerful but harder to install.

Comment: @WaleedZafar I have done you a PHP version - see end of answer.

Comment: This is what I get when I test this code:

Warning: imagepng(result.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/determinestencil.php on line 30

Comment: Your script does not have permission to write the output file - either write it somewhere where it does have permission, or change the permissions.